# How To Draw A Line In A RichTextBox Control

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have a RichTextBox control used to display message items.  The richtextbox shows the old message and allows the user to add new text as a reply.

I am trying to find a way to add a grey line before each of the replies so the user knows it was a previous thread (like outlook).

I have tried using the graphics element but I cannot seem to get any lines created in my control at all.  The only way I can achieve a line is to use the `rtbMessage.AppendText("___________")`
The problem with this is I don't know how to detect the end of the line so I can stop.  Otherwise, it wraps onto the next line and looks messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RichTextBox control is not a graphical control like a canvas.

When I have to do something like what you are describing, I change the background color of the text in question.

Comment: I ended up using a Highlight_Text routine to search on the text (__________) and change the colour.  Not sure if it's the correct method, but works well and gives me the result I was looking for.  Thanks for the advice.